# How can I create a csv file on blob storage azure with Object c# .NET Core?

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-core, blob, azure-storage

I am trying to create a CSV file from an object and upload it on blob storage. I also want the column to have the same name as the property in the object. (.NET Core 5.0/C#)

Answer (score -1):

Please use the code below:

```
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TestKeyVault.Services
    {

    public class Sample
    { 
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }

    public class Demo
    {
        public async Task startAsync()
        {
            var Friends = new List<Sample> { 
                new Sample { FirstName="Naman",LastName="Sinha",Id = 1},
                new Sample {FirstName="Naman",LastName="Sinha",Id = 2},  
                new Sample {FirstName = "Naman", LastName = "Sinha", Id = 3}
            };

            string properties = string.Join(",", Friends[0].GetType().GetProperties().Select(i => i.Name));

            var info = from member in Friends
                       let record = string.Join(",", member.GetType().GetProperties().Select(j => j.GetValue(member)))
                       select record;

            var csv = new List<string>
            {
                properties
            };

            csv.AddRange(info);

            string newPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Data";

            // Determine whether the directory exists.  
            if (Directory.Exists(newPath))
                Directory.Delete(newPath, true);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);

            File.WriteAllLines(newPath + "/FileToBeUploaded.csv", csv);

            try
            {

                CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING");

                CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME");

                await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("FileToBeUploaded.csv");

                await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(newPath);

                Console.WriteLine("File Uploaded!");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File could not be downloaded due to: "+ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The code creates a CSV file from a sample object and generates a .csv file from it and then uploads it as a blob in the container of the specified storage account.
You just need to change class and namespace and specify the connection string of the Azure storage account and name of container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you say work, but not the way i want, i want to have each value in different column.
Exemple: In A column, just the FirstName with it's values below.